# polynomials with complex coefficients (How to begin)

Tags: complex-analysis

I would just like to ask how do you begin with this problem cause my knowledge of complex numbers is a little rusty. Thanks in advance for any tip you gave.
$$
                               z^5-iz^3+iz^2+1=0$$
Find all complex sollutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z^5-iz^3+iz^2+1=0$$
$$\Rightarrow z^3(z^2-i)+i(z^2-i)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow (z^2-i)(z^3+i)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow (z^2-i)(z^3-iz^2+iz^2+z-z+i)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow (z^2-i)(z^2(z-i)+iz(z-i)-(z-i))=0$$
$$\Rightarrow (z-i)(z^2-i)(z^2+iz-1)=0$$
$$ (1)\ z^2-i=0 \Rightarrow z^2=1 \angle \frac{\pi}{2}\Rightarrow z=1 \angle \frac{\pi}{4} +\pi k\ (k=0,1)$$
$$\Rightarrow z=i\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4} +\pi k\right) + \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4} +\pi k\right)=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1+i)$$
$$(2)\ z-i=0 \Rightarrow z=i$$
$$(3)\ z^2 +iz-1=0 \Rightarrow z=\frac{-i \pm \sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$\therefore z_1 = i$$
$$\therefore z_2 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i$$
$$\therefore z_3 = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i$$
$$\therefore z_4 = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i$$
$$\therefore z_5 = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i$$

Comment: Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Luka2018 I edited the answer because I felt ferrari's method may make the simple problem unnecessarily complicated. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The same way as if it was real polynomial, only that - as you can see - complex coefficients are allowed too.
All you have to know is $i^2=-1$.

**Hints:** $iz^2+1=i(z^2-i)$, so you can pull out $z^2-i$.
For a complex number $a$, the equation $z^n=a$ can be solved by polar coordinates or exponential form of $z$, and the solution is always a regular $n$-gon in the complex plane.

Comment: thanks that really helps a lot :)